# Uploading file via FTP using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I am trying to upload a file using the FTP class in CodeIgniter. For that I have written the following:

```
        $this->load->library('ftp');

        $config['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
        $config['username'] = 'localftp';
        $config['password'] = '';
        $config['debug'] = TRUE;

        $this->ftp->connect($config);

        $this->ftp->upload($_FILES['book_file']['tmp_name'], asset_url()."books/" . $_FILES['book_file']['name'], "ascii", 0775);

        $this->ftp->close();
```

but it is showing me :

> Unable to upload the specified file. Please check your path.

I am using XAMPP FileZilla to connect to my FTP host. For that I have created the user `localftp` with no password. And this user has all the permissions on the host.

and this is my local XAMPP server logging:

```
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> Connected, sending welcome message...
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> USER localftp
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 331 Password required for localftp
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> PASS
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - localftp (127.0.0.1)> 230 Logged on
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - localftp (127.0.0.1)> PASV
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - localftp (127.0.0.1)> 227 Entering Passive Mode    (127,0,0,1,205,219)
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - localftp (127.0.0.1)> TYPE A
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - localftp (127.0.0.1)> 200 Type set to A
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - localftp (127.0.0.1)> STOR   http://localhost/International/public/books/ftpupload.pdf
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - localftp (127.0.0.1)> 550 Filename invalid
  (000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - localftp (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
```

on the second last line it is saying 550 filename invalid.. I think this is my problem.. Please can any one help me out to solve this issue..

Comment: check this url. Same problem discussed here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/64329/

Comment: thank @kumar_v but in my case my files are found by the ftp upload method but the path is giving me issue..i am not sure about this, but it seems to be this only to me..

Comment: You can see some related question located in right side in SO window. So you may get some idea from them

Comment: Thanks @kumar_v but just because i have not found any solution.. i had asked this question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right there in the log:

```
(000016)24-Dec-13 23:27:05 PM - localftp (127.0.0.1)> STOR http://localhost/International/public/books/ftpupload.pdf
```

You are trying to name the file

```
http://localhost/International/public/books/ftpupload.pdf
```

which is not a valid filename.

Try removing `asset_url()`:

```
$this->ftp->upload($_FILES['book_file']['tmp_name'], "books/" . $_FILES['book_file']['name'], "ascii", 0775);
```

Comment: sir, can you suggest me the path..what should i set path..according to the path given by me in this question

Comment: i have assigen the sharefolder as E:/tempdir to the user localftp..when setting the ftp user using xampp

Comment: I updated the answer. Please read the documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/ftp.html

Comment: thank you very much sir i solved my problem..but not on my local server but on my online server..and is done for me..thank you sir again..your answer gave me idea.. :)

Answer (score 0):

un-comment this `anon_upload_enable=YES` in `vsftpd.conf`

location `etc/vsftpd`

and restart ftp using > `systemctl restart vsftpd`

don't use `asset-url()`